# Como funciona este "melhores do mês/trimestre/ano"?

Tags: suporte, reputação, perfil

Como funciona este "melhores do mês/trimestre/ano"? Acessei a página de perfis do SOpt e vi dois perfis com reputação/medalhas/resposta bem dispares entre si sendo o que tinha uma reputação bem inferior tinha um "melhores do mês" mais alto do que o de maior reputação. Veja as imagens.

Menor pontuação:

[image: Menor pontuação]

Maior pontuação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Na verdade quanto menor o número, quer dizer que mais alto o usuário está no *ranking*. Seria como dizer:

"O usuário X está entre os 5 melhores desse mês, enquanto o usuário Y está entre os 100 melhores desse mês."

Só que o texto que mostra no perfil está mostrando em porcentagem, logo, suponha que temos 1.000 usuários no site, o primeiro estaria entre os 5/1.000 melhores do mês, que resultaria estar entre os 0,5% melhores, enquanto o segundo estaria entre os melhores 10%.

Outro ponto é que no perfil mostra o quão melhor o usuário é no(a) semana/mês/trimestre/ano naquilo que for mais vantajoso para ele, dependendo da pontuação do usuário nesses períodos.

Como exemplo, podemos ver o [perfil do Guilherme Bernal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/429/guilherme-bernal) que anda meio sumido, e consequentemente ele não está muito bem pontuado nos rankings da semana, mês e trimestre, logo no perfil dele mostra o que é mais vantajoso para ele, que é `melhores 2% de todos`

Comment: Quando a dúvida é de matemática, ninguém melhor que o Math pra responder :P